# Gaussian kernel formulation in diffusion models for deep neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03585.pdf

I believe this is one of the first papers using diffusion models for deep neural networks. On page 15, the forward Gaussian diffusion kernel is defined as:

$q(x^{(t)} \mid x^{(t-1)}) = \mathcal{N}(x^{(t)} ; x^{(t-1)} \sqrt{1 - \beta_t}, \mathbf{I} \beta_t )$

I see this on all other papers on diffusion models, but how is this derived? Thanks